# Java String.split() Regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string:

```
String str = "a + b - c * d / e < f > g >= h <= i == j";
```

I want to split the string on all of the operators, but include the operators in the array, so the resulting array looks like:

```
[a , +,  b , -,  c , *,  d , /,  e , <,  f , >,  g , >=,  h , <=,  i , ==,  j]
```

I've got this currently:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "a + b - c * d / e < f > g >= h <= i == j";
    String reg = "((?<=[<=|>=|==|\\+|\\*|\\-|<|>|/|=])|(?=[<=|>=|==|\\+|\\*|\\-|<|>|/|=]))";

    String[] res = str.split(reg);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
}
```

This is pretty close, it gives:

```
[a , +,  b , -,  c , *,  d , /,  e , <,  f , >,  g , >, =,  h , <, =,  i , =, =,  j]
```

Is there something I can do to this to make the multiple character operators appear in the array like I want them to?

And as a secondary question that isn't nearly as important, is there a way in the regex to trim the whitespace off from around the letters?

Comment: You could just split by spaces in your example expression to get the result you want.

Comment: for your secondary question: String has a trim function: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Comment: @Jeffrey: The spaces won't necessarily be there.  I have the spaces in there for ease of readability, but it could be any combination of spaces or none.  Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: @user306848: Yeah, I know about trim, I was just curious if it was possible in the regex.  Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
String[] ops = str.split("\\s*[a-zA-Z]+\\s*");
String[] notops = str.split("\\s*[^a-zA-Z]+\\s*");
String[] res = new String[ops.length+notops.length-1];
for(int i=0; i<res.length; i++) res[i] = i%2==0 ? notops[i/2] : ops[i/2+1];
```

This should do it. Everything nicely stored in `res`.

Comment: Yeap, this works, just strip off the leading element from the array (which is empty)

Comment: After coming back, this seems like the best way to do it.  I'd like to have done it in the regex, but this will work perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Any explanation?

Answer (score 20):

```
str.split (" ") 
res27: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(a, +, b, -, c, *, d, /, e, <, f, >, g, >=, h, <=, i, ==, j)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    String str = "a + b - c * d / e < f > g >= h <= i == j";
    String reg = "\\s*[a-zA-Z]+";

    String[] res = str.split(reg);
    for (String out : res) {
        if (!"".equals(out)) {
            System.out.print(out);
        }
    }
```

Output : + - * / < > >= <= ==

Answer (score 1):

You could split on a word boundary with \b

Comment: Did you try it? You’re going to have a problem.

Comment: OK, I admit it, I tested it in .NET and it worked. Removing the empty entries should be trivial, and removing the spaces in the string is surely easily accomplished with a .replaceAll before applying the Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Can you invert your regex so split by the non operation characters?

```
String ops[] = string.split("[a-z]")
// ops == [+, -, *, /, <, >, >=, <=, == ]
```

This obviously doesn't return the variables in the array. Maybe you can interleave two splits (one by the operators, one by the variables)

Comment: While not the exact solution, it did give me the idea that worked!  Thanks!  I'll edit the main post for the solution!

Answer (score -4):

You could also do something like:

```
String str = "a + b - c * d / e < f > g >= h <= i == j";
String[] arr = str.split("(?<=\\G(\\w+(?!\\w+)|==|<=|>=|\\+|/|\\*|-|(<|>)(?!=)))\\s*");
```

It handles white spaces and words of variable length and produces the array:

```
[a, +, b, -, c, *, d, /, e, <, f, >, g, >=, h, <=, i, ==, j]
```