# Split String into Array based on multiple delimiters in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to split a string into two different arrays based on multiple values

For example user inputs in the console window

```
   2+4/8*9
```

I want only the numbers to be in an array

```
Arr[0] = 2;
Arr[1] = 4;
Arr[2] = 8;
Arr[3] = 9;
```

And then

```
Operator[0] = +;
Operator[1] = /;
Operator[2] = *;
```

I am familiar with split method that uses only one delimiter but how will I be able to split the string based on various number of delimiters?

Following is the latest code I have tried by looking at various articles on the internet but getting error

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter input");
s = in.toString();

String [] operators = s.split("+|-|*|/"); //Also tried s.split("\\+\\-\\*\\/")

for(int i = 0; i<operators.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(operators[i]);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java String.split() Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856916/java-string-split-regex)

Comment: Use Spring.split() method and pass the Regex as an argument to the method.

Answer (score 1):

The string argument in `split` is a *regular expression*.

`*`, `+`, `-`, and `/` have special meanings in a regular expression. (The asterisk means "match any").

You need to *escape* them if you want to match them as exact symbols.

To do that use `\\*` etc. `\*` means a literal asterisk in a regular expression: in Java you need to *escape* the backslash; you do that by writing `\\`.

So you ought to use something like

`\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/`

Comment: Tried this now getting this error java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}
][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q
\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String str = "2+2-4*5/6";
str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
String[] Arr = str.replaceAll("[\\+\\-\\*\\/]", " ").split(" ");
String[] Operator = str.replaceAll("[0-9]", " ").split(" ");
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex we can split the expression and store the operand in String[]

`String[] t = st.split("-|\\#|\\(|\\)|\\{|\\}|\\<|\\>|\\s+|\\(\\\"|\\;");`

The regex expression split String based on "-, #, (, ), {, }, <, >, space, ;, #"
for character like "(double quote) and (backlash) then iterate the elements of String and remove the char.

Answer (score 0):

Use non-digit Regex to split your string:

```
String input     = "14*6+22";
String[] spl     = input.split("\\D");
char[] operation = input.replaceAll("\\w", "").toCharArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(spl));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(operation));
```