# How to split a String into two arrays based on a delimiter in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a String as below

```
String combinedString = "10.15%34.23%67.8% 89.00%100.00%44.44%";
```

As you can see above, there is a space between 67.8% and 89.00%

I would want to split them into two String arrays or two strings as below

```
String[] firstStringArray = {10.15%,34.23%,67.8%};
String[] secondStringArray = {89.00%, 100.00%, 44.44%};
```

or

```
String firstString = "10.15%34.23%67.8%";
String secondString = "89.00%100.00%44.44%";
```

Any idea on this please?

Comment: Java has a .split function that takes in a delimeter. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017480/split-string-into-array-based-on-multiple-delimiters-in-java

Comment: please share what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use `String.split(" ")` as follows:

```
String combinedString = "10.15%34.23%67.8% 89.00%100.00%44.44%";
String firstString = combinedString.split(" ")[0];
String secondString  = combinedString.split(" ")[1];

System.out.println(firstString);
System.out.println(secondString);
```

Output would look like this:

```
10.15%34.23%67.8%
89.00%100.00%44.44%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the white-space regex to split string based on delimiter of space, snippet as below,

```
    String str = "10.15%34.23%67.8% 89.00%100.00%44.44%";
    String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```