# Split string to brackets, but keep them in Java

Tags: java, split

I want to split string to brackets ( [] and () ), however I didn't find a good solution.
Splitting them to "[" and "(" didn't really help.
Basically I want to turn

```
[str1 str2] (str3 str4) hello world
```

to

```
- [str1 str2]
- (str3 str4)
- hello world
```

EDIT:

I have this regex now: \s+(?![^[][*]])
But I can't really seem to add () (it ignores stuffs inside [] )

EDIT 2:

Marked as duplicate. My question is to keep strings in bracket together, not to split by symbol.

Comment: what if you have [[str1 str2] strA] (str3 str4)???

Comment: String::split(regex)?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Should be "[[str1 str2] strA]" and "(str3 str4)". But I wouldn't allow that kind of string.

Comment: @CraigR8806 I don't really have experience with regexes. :l

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856916/java-string-split-regex

Comment: Have you tried using `indexOf`? Although it is not using regex but it's simple.

Comment: @CraigR8806 \s+(?![^\[][*\]]) I have this now, works for [], but not for ().
@ HardikModha Forgot to mention: There could be more [] or ().

Comment: `indexOf` has several overloads.  The one I believe Hardik was meaning is `haystack.indexOf(needle, startingPos)` where `startingPos` is the numerical index into the string of which to start looking.  In essence you could "leap-frog" from `needle` to `needle` calling `indexOf` multiple times.  This can get messy and verbose though, but it is a simpler solution.  That's a great start for not being very familiar with RegEx!  I will try to work you up a solution

Comment: @CraigR8806 Yeah, I know it's messy and not an efficient one. But if [] or () would occur only single time then it's worth trying.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But I'd have to look for brackets, and ignore others until it's not closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets you close (it matches the strings within the square brackets and parentheses, but not the "hello world" at the end:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SplitRegex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The search string
        String str = "[str1 str2] (str3 str4) hello world";

        // The Regular expression (Finds [(word)] tokens)
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[\\(\\[]([^\\]\\)]*)[\\]\\)]");

        // Match the string with the pattern
        Matcher m = pt.matcher(str);

        // If results are found
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0)); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Had to rewrite it a bit, and works perfect! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that is a bit more compact:

```
String str = "[str1 str2] (str3 str4) hello world";
String[] seperatedWords = str.split("\\r+(?:\\(.*\\))|(?:[.*])");
```