# Split a string in Java by symbols

Tags: java, split

The request is simple in words, but then it took a twist
Basically what I need is not only to split a string, but save the"symbols"and later be able to show them

Here's how it works:

**Input:**

Once upon a time there was a kingdom far, far away

On this kingdom lived a princess

And she was happy by herself

**Output:**

Once, 1 time, line 1-column 1

upon, 1 time, line 1-column 6

a, 3 times, line 1-column 11, line 1-column 28, line 2-column 23

...

Also should be able to : not consider spaces, \n and \f on them, but like do consider the "," so splitting by spaces would not give "far," and "far" as different symbols, just as "," is a symbol on it's own

Is there any way on which the split method could consider multiple parameters?
Not to mention I am not sure if there is a better way than a for loop to count the line and column on which each "symbol" is repeated

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856916/java-string-split-regex

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into symbols, keep the symbols as keys in the hash map and their count in corresponding hash map values.

Example:

```
Map<String, Integer> tokensWithCounts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
String[] tokens = str.split("\\s*[a-zA-Z]+\\s*");
List<String> tokensList = Arrays.asList(tokens);
for(String token : tokenList){
    if(tokensWithCounts.get(token) == null){
        tokensWithCounts.put(token, 0);
    }
    tokensWithCounts.put(token, tokensWithCounts.get(token) + 1);
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I got the question wrong. You will keep the values in a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`. Tokens will still be keys, List will have all occurrences of the token in the form of "line 1-column 1". The count of occurrences is the `.size()` of the `List<String>` that is stored in the HashMap.