# How to split multi-line string in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I have the following data text :

```
[data]A[/data]
aaa
4 5 8 
[data]B[/data]
bbb
3 1 9 
[data]C[/data]
ccc
6 5 2
...
```

I want to split them in to the following 3 units :

1st unit :

```
[data]A[/data]
aaa
4 5 8
```

2nd  unit :

```
[data]B[/data]
bbb
3 1 9
```

3rd unit :

```
[data]C[/data]
ccc
6 5 2
```

So my code looks like this :

```
String Units[]=dataText.split("[data]");
```

Yet, this doesn't do it properly, what's the right way to split it ?

If I use regex, how should I write the expression ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java String.split() Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856916/java-string-split-regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex `(?ms)(?<=.)(?=^\[)`:

```
    String[] units = dataText.split("(?ms)(?<=.)(?=^\\[)");
```

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/j8iJol/1) for demo.

Explanation:

```
(?ms)       Turn on MULTILINE ('^' and '$' match after/before line terminator)
                and DOTALL (aka "single line", '.' matches any character)
(?<=.)      Must be preceded by a character (needs 's' flag)
               Used to prevent matching very first '['
(?=^\[)     Must be followed by a '[' at the beginning of a line (needs 'm' flag)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a BufferedReader:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(dataString));
```

Iterate the String like this:

```
int lineCounter = 0;
int arrayCounter = 0;
String line = null;
while( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
{
    units[arrayCounter] += line;
    if (lineCounter >= 2) {
        arrayCounter++;
        lineCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but how to decide the size of units ? My dataString could include hounds of units.

Comment: Your example looked like 3 lines per unit. If this size is not constant, you will have to use a regex.

Comment: Yes, it is a clean solution.

Comment: What I meant was, each unit has 3 lines, that's fixed, but there could be 216 units or 567 units, so how to create "String units=new String[ ??? ]"

Comment: You have to use a collection like ArrayList.