# How to use java regex to do job like sed?

Tags: java, regex, sed, match, token

E.g. I've got an input string:

```
2 + 5* 61.2 -(32.5+7)/ 8
```

I want to split this string into tokens of decimals and operators(+-*/and parentheses), remove blanks(space and tab) add commas in between. The expected output:

```
2,+,5,*,61.2,-,(,32.5,+,7,),/,8
```

I know I can do this in sed by just one command:

```
sed -E 's/ |\t//g;s/([-\+\*\/)(])/,\1,/g;s/,+/,/g'
```

My question: how to use java regex to achieve this? I see java regex is more used to "match/filter" known pattern, can it do "edit" just like sed does?

Appreciate your solutions, thanks.

Comment: Sed would use regex in the same way and probably does the editing internally. Sure you can extract the tokens in Java and combine them into a new string if you want to.

Comment: You can use string.split() for this.
Reed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856916/java-string-split-regex

Comment: That is not one sed command, that is three sed commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by iterating over matched positions of your regexp like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    String input = "2 + 5* 61.2 -(32.5+7)/ 8";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|[()+\\-\\*\\/]{1}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: the regular expression given fits your particular example but might need rework to support more generic cases.